# How to Set TTL in MongoDB uing C# MongoDriver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using MongoDb in c# . I insert a  Student Like below

```
_client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings
{
    Server = new MongoServerAddress("172.1.9.8", 27017)
});
_database = _client.GetDatabase("MongoSample");

Student st = new Student()
{
    Name = "Ali",
    Family = "Valid",
    Age = 25,
    expireAt = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)
};
var collection = _database.GetCollection<Student>("Students");
collection.InsertOne(st);
```

I want to set a `TTL`  to Remove data after some seconds , I try to do that like this :

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<Student>("Students");
var indexs = collection.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<Student>.IndexKeys.Ascending("Name"),
            new CreateIndexOptions { ExpireAfter = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) });

collection.InsertOne(st);
```

but it does not work.
my model is :

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("expireAt")]
    public DateTime expireAt { get; set; }
}
```

Note : and I have problem with `DateTime` , stored data  in db is different with Set Date in `Visual Studio`

Comment: If you want to use `expireAt` then the seconds on the interval needs to be `0`. [Expire Documents at a Specific Clock Time](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time). If you are looking for expiry after seconds, then the TTL sheduler only runs once every minute and thus 10 seconds too small an interval. But you do need to pick a behavior and stick to it.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you so much .

Comment: @NeilLunn does it necessary to have `ExpireAt` in my `Student ` Model ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading Mongodb documents again , there was a mistake in my code to add `Index` . there some restriction to work `TTL` .

**If the indexed field in a document is not a date or an array that holds a date value(s), the document will not expire.**

I'v tried to set Index on `Name` and it does not contain `Date`.

below code works fine .

```
var indexKeysDefinition = Builders<Student>.IndexKeys.Ascending("expireAt");
var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions { ExpireAfter = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60) };
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<Student>(indexKeysDefinition, indexOptions);
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(indexModel);
```

thank for [@NeilLunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) .

Answer (score 4):

For Updated version 2.8 and above to help more people.

```
var keys = Builders<ResponseCache>.IndexKeys.Ascending("expireAt");
var model = new CreateIndexModel<ResponseCache>(keys, new CreateIndexOptions() { ExpireAfter = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0) });
try
{
    _repository.Indexes.CreateOne(model);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

_repository.InsertOne(responseCache);
```

Create Index with TTL 15 Min. it is perfectly working fine for me.

Thanks