# How to create expire index in MongoDB using .NET api

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have collection with `CreatedAt` field, is there a way to create expire index using .NET api

I want to achieve is something like this
`db.log_events.createIndex( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )`

but without using string, only api.

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870811/set-ttl-doesnt-work-in-mongodb-c-sharp what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use it:

```
var myIndex = new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<MyEntity>().Ascending(c => c.CreatedAt);
myCollection
    .Indexes
    .CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<MyEntity>(myIndex, new CreateIndexOptions { ExpireAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) }));
```